# Unable to download zip file using NodeJS res.download

Tags: node.js, download

I have a process that selects a folder, zips the contents, and downloads the zip file to the downloads folder of the user. It was working quite well, but of late fails on larger zip files. The underlying code follows.

```
let type = req.body.type;
let path = req.body.path;
let name = req.body.name;

const outFile = '/tmp/' + userJson.user_id + '-' + name + '.zip';

try {
    const zip = new AdmZip();
    
    if (fs.existsSync(outFile)) {
        fs.unlinkSync(outFile);
    }

    zip.addLocalFolder(path);
    zip.writeZip(outfile);

    res.download(outfile, function(err) { console.log(err)});
catch (e) {
    logger.error("Zip file failed with exception " + e);
}
```

In the downloaded files list, the download shows as failed. When you click on the file in the browser downloads list, the message 'The Compressed (zipped) Folder {zipname} is invalid' pops up.

Comment: 1. client side timeout, 2. server side timeout, 3. /tmp (or os disk itself is full) ... OR 4. os cleanup of /tmp removed the temporary file. i guess it could be something else, but it's probably one of those four. good luck. also, you might want to look at those logs ;)

Comment: Process of elmination: logs provide no help, and /tmp directory has plenty of space on it and the temporary file is not being prematurely removed. That leaves client side timeout or server side timeout. Is there a way to modify the default values for timeout on each side to prevent that from being the issue?

Comment: You'll have control over the server side timeout, but without any details on your hosting i can't even begin to throw guesses at you. You won't have control over the client side timeout, but typically if the server is actively communicating with the client, it should continue accepting the download. Have you timed how long it takes for the download to stop working to see if it's consistent?